# How to fix Visual studio code - PHP Inteliphense shows PHP executable path error

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, wamp

I am new to visual studio code. Using it as an editor to my CI project. Installed PHP Intelephense , but  it keeps on showing set php executable path and that should point to php.exe. My WAMP installation is also fresh. All I can find is php.ini in WAMP folder, but not php.exe. Is that something I have to download separately or ? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

My question is where exactly is php.exe located in wamp folder? Even to set PATH environment variable, I am not able to locate this file. Neither it is set with WAMP installation. Latest Installation of wamp added 3 different versions of PHP, and 7.3.14 is default selected.

any solution for this?

Comment: [This](http://blog.astemplates.com/change-php-version-wamp/) show how you can change the PHP version used by WAMP. If there is no PHP, then something went wrong installing WAMP....

Comment: In the configuration file for Visual Studio Code ('settings.json'), there should be a line `"php.validate.executablePath": ""`. I can be left empty if PHP.exe can be found via the PATH.